# make column as same from id

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I need your help, I have a table whith two column, an id and numpos, i want that the id and numops has the same result.

exemple :

```
$cnx = mysql_connect( "localhost", "root", "" );
$db = mysql_select_db( "maincourante" );

$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO ops (id) values('')");

$req = mysql_query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as id FROM ops");
$data = mysql_fetch_array($req);

$upd = mysql_query("UPDATE `ops` SET `numops`=`idops` WHERE `idops`=$data");

mysql_query($upd, $cnx) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_close();`
```

thanks for your help

Comment: yes, i don't understand what is my problem...

Comment: If you don't have a problem, this isn't a question.

Comment: i have a problem... the INSERT work fine and the UPDATE work too but the UPDATE put 0 all the time. not what i need, (numops 1 for id 1, numops 2 for id 2...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
This works for mysql:

```
 INSERT INTO ops (`numops`) VALUES ((SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID())+1);
```

This works for php:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO ops (`numops`) VALUES (0)");
mysql_query("UPDATE ops `numops` ='".mysql_insert_id()."' WHERE `id` = '".mysql_insert_id()."'");
```

Or

```
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO ops (`numops`) VALUES ('".mysql_insert_id()."')"); 
// this will only works if there is the same query executed before this.
```

Comment: first, thanks. I have try and this return 1 for all id. i am lost

Comment: @user1825668 is `id` in `numops` is your primary key? because it must be primary key if you want this to work

Comment: id is primary key with auto-increment, numops is only an int. i test to make numops as auto-increment or primary but it is impossible because only one can be

Comment: ok guys thank you so much.

this code work fine for me.

`$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO ops (`idops`) VALUES ('')");
 $upd = mysql_query("UPDATE ops SET `numops` = `idops` WHERE `idops` = '".mysql_insert_id()."'");`

Comment: @user1825668 at the left side of the answer you'll see a up down arrow and a zero number, if your happy w/ the answer, click up arrow. to accept the answer, click the check icon below that.

Comment: ok thanks i cannot vote up at this time because i have less than 15 reputation but up, up, up